# Protractor windows authentication

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

How would I set/pass windows authentication user credentials in a protractor test? I am not sure how selenium handle's this but there must be a way for setting these values?

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? Are you trying to pass these credentials into a windows dialog or would you like to pass them into the browser?

Comment: Whichever way selenium will allow me to do it! I just need to find a way of passing the credentials in. With windows auth, I think dialog box is the only way to go (correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: See if this article helps http://learn-automation.com/handle-windows-authentication-using-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Ok yes, I can pass in credentials via url, at least for the chrome driver. Thanks.

Comment: I'll post as an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (16/02/2021)**

If you are using lastest chrome and if you wanted to bypass the windows login prompt, use
[AuthServerWhitelist](https://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AuthServerWhitelist)

```
capabilities: {
        browserName: "chrome",
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ["--auth-server-whitelist=*localhost*, *.authserver.com"]
        }
    }
```